# setInterval(); in AS

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have 5 different images in 5 different frames, and i need animate them like a slider.

I build this code:

```
function playNextFrame(){
        if(_root._currentframe+1 == 7) {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }else{
            gotoAndStop(_currentframe+1);
        }
}

 var myTimer = setInterval(playNextFrame, 5000);
```

But when I click in the navigations buttons
(per example)

```
but1.onRelease = function() {
    gotoAndStop(2);
};
```

it goes to random frames at random times :/

If you can help me with fade effects, would also be of great help. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on the button you will also need to clear the interval so that it no longer fires. This is what causes your random frame jumps probably.

```
but1.onRelease = function() {
clearInterval(myTimer)
gotoAndStop(2);};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it don't work. :/
I tried this:
`but1.onRelease = function() {
 clearInterval(myTimer);
 gotoAndStop(2);
 myTimer = setInterval(playNextFrame, 5000);
};`

Comment: New update:
I used your code and added cleadInterval after:
`function playNextFrame(){` and added `var myTimer = setInterval(playNextFrame, 5000);` in each image frame. This only happened because I realized that with your code, when you click the button 1 it always worked, but with the other he stopped. Thanks man!